# Information about device, platform etc

Tags: compact-framework

I would like to get some information about the device, os etc. from the device running my app.
I need to log this data so i can run some diagnostics later.

Now i think that this data is located in Microsoft.Win32.Registry but that means i need to know all the keys to access values.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if it exists in the CF, but normally the `Environment`-Type has a lot of information about the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on exactly what information you want, but you probably want to P/Invoke [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932539.aspx) with parameters like SPI_GETOEMINFO, SPI_GETPLATFORMMANUFACTURER, SPI_GETPLATFORMNAME, SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE and SPI_GETPLATFORMVERSION.

[MSDN has an example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229660(VS.90).aspx).

**EDIT**

Here are some values for you:

```
#define SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE 257
#define SPI_GETOEMINFO 258
#define SPI_GETPROJECTNAME 259
#define SPI_GETPLATFORMNAME 260
#define SPI_GETBOOTMENAME 261
#define SPI_GETPLATFORMMANUFACTURER 262
#define SPI_GETUUID 263
#define SPI_GETGUIDPATTERN 264
```

For the version I'd just pull Environment.OSVersion.Version and compare to [this version list](http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/mobiledeveloper/listofakus/).

Comment: thanx again ctacke! The only problem i have is getting SPI_GETPLATFORMVERSION. Maybe im thinking wrong but i need to get what version of OS is the client running. I have checked winuser.h file where this stuff is listed but i cant find anything that would get me the OS version. Any idea?

Comment: i got the OS version with System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString(); Thanx again ctacke!